# SSRS export to PDF formatting different deployed versus VS export

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts

If I view the SSRS report and preview the results, then chose to export the preview to PDF the export looks perfect. (The fonts display correctly and are formatted nicely.)

When I deploy the report to IIS and go through the web report using IE and choose to export the results to PDF from inside IE the PDF is not formatted nicely. One particular type of barcode font gets all scrunched up.

Why would the export to PDF feature differ when I'm in Visual Studio versus in IE viewing the IIS deployed report?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, VS tries to replicate the SSRS environment but doesn't do it faithfully. I would therefore only use preview in the initial stages of development but polish and test the report on an actual server